# Faking an offer to get a counteroffer

Tags: negotiation, counter-offer

Is it advantageous for an employee of company X to tell them that they got a better offer from company Y (assuming it is fake) just to get company X to offer a better salary/offer?

I am asking because the company has been dishonest with me and harassed me.

Comment: What do you intend to do if your employer says "OK, fine, we'll take this as your resignation"?

Comment: The problem is that they could always call your bluff. If they don't counter-offer something that is acceptable to you, and you end up staying, then they will notice that this was just an empty threat.

Comment: You want to lie to and cheat your employers to get more money? That money will bring contentment?

Comment: @AIQ Some would also view it as an employee preventing their employer from cheating them.

Comment: This is an important question to have answered on this site because many people may wonder about it. It should have more visibility and thus be upvoted more. I think people often misuse the downvoting button to morally disapprove rather than judge whether the question and its answers should receive more visibility.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere And few would happen upon your wisdom if the question had -10 votes. What not to do can be just as important as what to do.

Answer (score 15):

> Is it advantageous for an employee of company X to tell them that he
> got a better offer from company Y (assuming it is fake) just to get
> company X to offer a better salary/offer?

No. Negotiate the offer/salary you wish to get. If they won't meet your offer then "faking" a better offer isn't going to change that. Don't play games.

Comment: Why can't I just say I got a better offer from another company and unless they are willing to match that, then I will leave for the other company.

Comment: Why be dishonest? Why not just negotiate for a raise?

Comment: Because the company has been dishonest with me and harassed me.

Comment: @TomJames Why do you want to work for a dishonest company which harassed you ?

Comment: @TomJames - So leave the company. If they are actually harassing you, why would you continue to work with individuals who harass you, no matter what your compensation might be

Comment: @TomJames Why would you trust a dishonest company that harassed you not to just fire you the second you imply you might leave? Or not to say they'll match/beat your competing "offer" and then not keep their promise? Can you real expect them to deal with you fairly?

Answer (score 10):

I've done this. It worked out in my favour. Just be aware that it's a very high-risk / high-reward kind of move.

---

**So should you do it?**

Here's my thought process:

This works a lot better if you *actually* have a backup offer. It means you can follow through on your ultimatum if needed. And you know for sure that you can actually be paid more somewhere else.

Now in my case, I was in the middle of looking for a better offer. But a situation occurred at my company which meant they really needed to keep me around.

So I could either wait to find another offer and play it safe. Or make an ultimatum now when I had maximum leverage, and be prepared to quit without another job to go to if it failed. That's the only reason I went into it without another offer to go to.

---

**If you are going to do it:**

Saying "I'll quit unless you pay me more" actually undermines your negotiating position. Because it suggests you're not *really* looking to quit, you're just fishing for a pay rise. If you want the best negotiation position then you have to *actually* quit, and make it clear that it's because your salary expectations aren't being met, and see if they'll try to change your mind.

In my case, I phoned my boss after work on a Monday and the conversation went like this:

"Hi [Boss/Director], I just wanted to let you know that I'll be handing in my notice at the Board Meeting on Wednesday."

[Long pause]

"Can I ask why?"

"Well [Boss], I've made it clear that I want to stay and I want to build this company. But not at this salary and not without a stake in it. And neither of those things seem to be happening, so I'm going somewhere else."

"Okay, let's talk tomorrow."

---

I got my salary doubled and equity in the company. But only because they really wanted to keep me and it would have been very painful to replace me on short notice.

Your mileage will vary.

If you're going to do this, you'd better be prepared for them to say "ok well we wish you the best of luck".

Comment: I know of a secretary who used a similar strategy, and it worked. Companies also bluff to employees and potential candidates.

Comment: I don't think you have done what the OP is suggesting. At no point did you lie to your employer or were trying to fake something.

Comment: @Hilmar I never explicitly said I had another offer, but I deliberately implied it and acted as if I had one. Which for this purpose is essentially the same thing.

Comment: No, it is absolutely NOT the same thing. Making someone think you MAY have a better option and outright lying to them are two totally different pairs of shoes. One is gambling (and I agree with you: very high risk / high reward), the other one is well... lying... you can be fired for one but not for the other if the company ever finds out...

Comment: Definitely NOT the same as the OP's situation, and the downside risk is tremendous as @Tode and Hilmar have already stated. This just isn't good advice.

Comment: @Tode I disagree. Every businessman I know would consider this a legitimate (though not necessarily advisable) negotiation tactic. Whether the other job actually exists doesn't matter, because you're quitting either way. Bluffing in a negotiation is a normal part of doing business.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to disagree with Joeqwerty's answer and say it *might* get you a counteroffer but it seems high-risk. If the company have played hard-ball with you in previous salary negotiations or think you'll never leave, then *maybe* your offer would make them give you a counteroffer. But if it doesn't what will you do; drag out your notice period while you find an actual new job? pretend you've changed your mind and actually stay? Even worse would be if you work somewhere where they could say "fine, leave then. Today can be your last day".

For me personally, I'm not sure the risk would make it more worth doing more than negotiating a raise or just actually leaving (especially after your comment about how they treat you)

Answer (score 4):

> Is it advantageous for an employee of company X to tell them that he got a better offer from company Y (assuming it is fake) just to get company X to offer a better salary/offer?

Absolutely not.

1. Don't lie. Lying is one of the worst things you can do. If you get caught not only are you likely to get fired for cause, you will end up on the "do not hire" list and your professional reputation could take severe damage.
2. What you are going to do if they call your bluff? "Can you show us the offer?", "Congratulations to your new job!". "When will your last day be?"

Counter offers happen rarely when you threaten to quit, they happen when you actually quit. Whether you have a new offer in hand or not is not really relevant other than it sets a benchmark for a counter offer.

Comment: Call me crazy but I don't think companies have "do not hire lists" going around unless it's a very nieche job that only a handful of people can do.

Comment: Many companies definitely have "do not hire" lists. It's build in into most commercial application management systems too.

Answer (score 3):

Don't put yourself in a situation where *your* worth is solely decided by someone else's judgement.

In other words, it really does not (at least, should not) matter to organisation X what organisation Y is willing to pay for you - all that matters is what organisation X is willing to pay for you based on the value you provide. This is something absolute - no strong reference <sup>note</sup> to another organisation or their offer (amount).

IMHO, it's always easier to deal or negotiate based on something that you have in you (your knowledge, expertise, experience, value addition), not what someone else told you (in form of offer).

So, counteroffer or not, it's not relevant. Ask what you feel is acceptable compensation, and if you don't get it, be ready to find it from somewhere else. No need to fake anything - sticking to the truth and facts help you have a good night's sleep, above everything.

---

Note: You should very well do your market research to understand how much of your skills are worth, but you need to express that reason / logic while negotiating, all you should ask for a compensation which you seem fair and acceptable.